# Understanding .get() method for nested dictionaries

Tags: python

I have the following nested dictionary and I'm trying to return the boolean of the value to the `['is_up']` key inside of a function:

```
ios_output = {'global': {'router_id': '10.10.10.1',
  'peers': {'10.10.10.2': {'local_as': 100,
    'remote_as': 100,
    'remote_id': '0.0.0.0',
    'is_up': False,
    'is_enabled': True,
    'description': '',
    'uptime': -1,
    'address_family': {'ipv4': {'received_prefixes': -1,
      'accepted_prefixes': -1,
      'sent_prefixes': -1}}},
   '10.10.10.3': {'local_as': 100,
    'remote_as': 100,
    'remote_id': '0.0.0.0',
    'is_up': False,
    'is_enabled': True,
    'description': '',
    'uptime': -1,
    'address_family': {'ipv4': {'received_prefixes': -1,
      'accepted_prefixes': -1,
      'sent_prefixes': -1}}},
   '10.10.10.5': {'local_as': 100,
    'remote_as': 100,
    'remote_id': '172.16.28.149',
    'is_up': True,
    'is_enabled': True,
    'description': '',
    'uptime': 3098,
    'address_family': {'ipv4': {'received_prefixes': 0,
      'accepted_prefixes': 0,
      'sent_prefixes': 0}}}}}}
```

The only way I've been able to get this work is by using a nested for loop:

```
for k, v in ios_output.items():
    for y in v.values():
        if type(y) == dict:
            for z in y.values():
                return z['is_up'] == True
```

When I replace the nested loop with this line:

```
return ios_output.get('global').get('peers').get('10.10.10.1').get('is_up') == True
```

I get:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' dictionary`

I'm of the opinion that there's got to be a better way to than leveraging a nested loop - which is why I'm attempting to use the `.get()` method but I believe I'm missing something. Thoughts?

Comment: There's no `'10.10.10.1'` key in `ios_output.get('global').get('peers')`.

Comment: Your get statement seems to only want to look for `is_up` in one particular nesting of dictionaries, while the loop searches through multiple dictionaries. Which parts of `ios_output` do you actually want to examine?

Comment: @HS-nebula: Sorry I posted this before correcting the flattened code, yes i get the same error for the key 10.10.10.3

Comment: @Will, I just want to get the value of 'is_up': True. Which in this case is True. I have a function that returns checks to see if the value of the key is True and returns a boolean True if the value of the key is True

Answer (score 3):

`10.10.10.1` is not present in your dict, hence the `AttributeError`.

That said, the `get` method accepts a second, default parameter, which is `None` by default.

That said, if you want to reach the specific node, you need to pass a second parameter, which would be an empty dict:

```
return ios_output.get('global', {}).get('peers', {}).get('10.10.10.1', {}).get('is_up')
```

Which, given that `10.10.10.1` doesn't exist would return `None`

Comment: you should just use exception handling here.

Comment: Thanks. What of a situation where I want to parse through the entire nested dictionary for each 'is_up' key?. In my original dictionary, suppose I'm searching for 'is_up' inside '10.10.10.3' and then I also need to check for the value of 'is_up' inside '10.10.10.5'; is there a way to do this without a loop?

the output of the dictionary is actually executed by a separate function inside my script and then I have a second function in the script that returns a boolean True for that dictionary. My nested for loop does the job; not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: That depends. A try-except block would be slower. Around 10% to be exact. Not an issue here but if you have to do it 100000000 times, it would make a difference.